Can I build arm32 docker files with dockerhub
I have DockerHub repository set up to autobuild my Dockerfile stored in a BitBucket repository. Every time a modification is made to the Dockerfile, and this works fine https://bitbucket.org/ijabz/songkongdocker/src/master/Dockerfile
I also have another Docker repository that points to a separate BitBucket repostitory https://bitbucket.org/ijabz/songkongdockerarm32/src/master/Dockerfile that builds an arm32 version of the application and I have been building this manually on an arm32 based qnap, but I have problems with my qnap so would like to be built on Dockerhub
I configured it but the build failed, its not clear to me if I have to do something special to build arm32 builds or if it is not possible
Dockerhub build fails as follows
....
    2024-06-18T11:35:16Z 
    2024-06-18T11:35:16Z #10 [build 2/4] RUN /opt/java/openjdk/bin/jlink --module-path=/opt/java/openjdk/jmods --add-modules java.desktop,java.datatransfer,java.logging,java.management,java.naming,java.net.http,java.prefs,java.scripting,java.sql,jdk.management,jdk.unsupported,jdk.jcmd,jdk.crypto.ec,jdk.dynalink --output /opt/songkong/jre
    2024-06-18T11:35:17Z #10 0.377 exec /bin/sh: exec format error
    2024-06-18T11:35:20Z #10 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c /opt/java/openjdk/bin/jlink --module-path=/opt/java/openjdk/jmods --add-modules java.desktop,java.datatransfer,java.logging,java.management,java.naming,java.net.http,java.prefs,java.scripting,java.sql,jdk.management,jdk.unsupported,jdk.jcmd,jdk.crypto.ec,jdk.dynalink --output /opt/songkong/jre]: exit code: 1
    2024-06-18T11:35:20Z ------
    2024-06-18T11:35:20Z  > [build 2/4] RUN /opt/java/openjdk/bin/jlink --module-path=/opt/java/openjdk/jmods --add-modules java.desktop,java.datatransfer,java.logging,java.management,java.naming,java.net.http,java.prefs,java.scripting,java.sql,jdk.management,jdk.unsupported,jdk.jcmd,jdk.crypto.ec,jdk.dynalink --output /opt/songkong/jre:
    2024-06-18T11:35:20Z #10 0.377 exec /bin/sh: exec format error
    2024-06-18T11:35:20Z ------
    2024-06-18T11:35:20Z ERROR: failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c /opt/java/openjdk/bin/jlink --module-path=/opt/java/openjdk/jmods --add-modules java.desktop,java.datatransfer,java.logging,java.management,java.naming,java.net.http,java.prefs,java.scripting,java.sql,jdk.management,jdk.unsupported,jdk.jcmd,jdk.crypto.ec,jdk.dynalink --output /opt/songkong/jre]: exit code: 1
    2024-06-18T11:35:20Z Build failed using Buildkit (1)

***Updated with attempt to use Zachs answer
Note I am just trying to build arm32 build not multibuild so
I haven't created the post_push file within Bitbucket I just created hooks folder and build file containing
#!/bin/bash

# Set up buildx. Inspecting ensures buildx is configured correctly and ready, and the final command runs a container to set up QEMU, enabling the Arm emulation for cross-platform building.
docker buildx create --name mybuilder --use
docker buildx inspect --bootstrap
docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset -p yes

# Build & push the arm/v7 image
docker buildx build --platform linux/arm/v7 -t songkong/songkong-arm32:latest -f Dockerfile --push .

I replaced
-t username/repository:tag-arm32

with
-t songkong/songkong-arm32:latest

So songkong is my dockerhub username, songkong-arm32 is the dockerhub repository (dont confuse with bitbucket repository) and I always tag as latest
This triggers an automated build on DockerHub and this built okay using qemu, however failed at the last stage trying to push tag as follows
2024-07-03T19:44:28Z Cloning into '.'...
2024-07-03T19:44:29Z Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address '18.205.93.1' to the list of known hosts.
2024-07-03T19:44:30Z Reset branch 'master'
2024-07-03T19:44:30Z Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
2024-07-03T19:44:30Z Executing build hook...
2024-07-03T19:44:39Z mybuilder
2024-07-03T19:44:39Z #1 [internal] booting buildkit
2024-07-03T19:44:39Z #1 pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1
2024-07-03T19:44:47Z #1 pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1 8.4s done
2024-07-03T19:44:47Z #1 creating container buildx_buildkit_mybuilder0
2024-07-03T19:44:51Z #1 creating container buildx_buildkit_mybuilder0 4.1s done
2024-07-03T19:44:51Z #1 DONE 12.5s
2024-07-03T19:44:51Z Name:          mybuilder
2024-07-03T19:44:51Z Driver:        docker-container
2024-07-03T19:44:51Z Last Activity: 2024-07-03 19:44:39 +0000 UTC
2024-07-03T19:44:51Z 
2024-07-03T19:44:51Z Nodes:
2024-07-03T19:44:51Z Name:      mybuilder0
2024-07-03T19:44:51Z Endpoint:  unix:///var/run/docker.sock
2024-07-03T19:44:51Z Status:    running
2024-07-03T19:44:51Z Buildkit:  v0.14.1
2024-07-03T19:44:51Z Platforms: linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2, linux/amd64/v3, linux/386
2024-07-03T19:44:51Z Unable to find image 'multiarch/qemu-user-static:latest' locally
2024-07-03T19:44:52Z latest: Pulling from multiarch/qemu-user-static
2024-07-03T19:44:52Z 205dae5015e7: Pulling fs layer
2024-07-03T19:44:52Z 816739e52091: Pulling fs layer
2024-07-03T19:44:52Z 30abb83a18eb: Pulling fs layer
2024-07-03T19:44:52Z 0657daef200b: Pulling fs layer
2024-07-03T19:44:52Z 30c9c93f40b9: Pulling fs layer
2024-07-03T19:44:52Z 0657daef200b: Waiting
2024-07-03T19:44:52Z 30c9c93f40b9: Waiting
2024-07-03T19:44:52Z 30abb83a18eb: Verifying Checksum
2024-07-03T19:44:52Z 30abb83a18eb: Download complete
2024-07-03T19:44:52Z 816739e52091: Verifying Checksum
2024-07-03T19:44:52Z 816739e52091: Download complete
2024-07-03T19:44:52Z 205dae5015e7: Verifying Checksum
2024-07-03T19:44:52Z 205dae5015e7: Download complete
2024-07-03T19:44:52Z 0657daef200b: Verifying Checksum
2024-07-03T19:44:52Z 0657daef200b: Download complete
2024-07-03T19:44:52Z 205dae5015e7: Pull complete
2024-07-03T19:44:53Z 816739e52091: Pull complete
2024-07-03T19:44:53Z 30abb83a18eb: Pull complete
2024-07-03T19:44:53Z 30c9c93f40b9: Verifying Checksum
2024-07-03T19:44:53Z 30c9c93f40b9: Download complete
2024-07-03T19:44:53Z 0657daef200b: Pull complete
2024-07-03T19:45:00Z 30c9c93f40b9: Pull complete
2024-07-03T19:45:00Z Digest: sha256:fe60359c92e86a43cc87b3d906006245f77bfc0565676b80004cc666e4feb9f0
2024-07-03T19:45:00Z Status: Downloaded newer image for multiarch/qemu-user-static:latest
2024-07-03T19:45:05Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-alpha-static as binfmt interpreter for alpha
2024-07-03T19:45:05Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static as binfmt interpreter for arm
2024-07-03T19:45:05Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-armeb-static as binfmt interpreter for armeb
2024-07-03T19:45:05Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-sparc-static as binfmt interpreter for sparc
2024-07-03T19:45:05Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-sparc32plus-static as binfmt interpreter for sparc32plus
2024-07-03T19:45:05Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-sparc64-static as binfmt interpreter for sparc64
2024-07-03T19:45:05Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-ppc-static as binfmt interpreter for ppc
2024-07-03T19:45:05Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-ppc64-static as binfmt interpreter for ppc64
2024-07-03T19:45:05Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-ppc64le-static as binfmt interpreter for ppc64le
2024-07-03T19:45:05Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-m68k-static as binfmt interpreter for m68k
2024-07-03T19:45:05Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-mips-static as binfmt interpreter for mips
2024-07-03T19:45:05Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-mipsel-static as binfmt interpreter for mipsel
2024-07-03T19:45:05Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-mipsn32-static as binfmt interpreter for mipsn32
2024-07-03T19:45:05Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-mipsn32el-static as binfmt interpreter for mipsn32el
2024-07-03T19:45:05Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-mips64-static as binfmt interpreter for mips64
2024-07-03T19:45:05Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-mips64el-static as binfmt interpreter for mips64el
2024-07-03T19:45:05Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-sh4-static as binfmt interpreter for sh4
2024-07-03T19:45:05Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-sh4eb-static as binfmt interpreter for sh4eb
2024-07-03T19:45:05Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-s390x-static as binfmt interpreter for s390x
2024-07-03T19:45:05Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-aarch64-static as binfmt interpreter for aarch64
2024-07-03T19:45:05Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-aarch64_be-static as binfmt interpreter for aarch64_be
2024-07-03T19:45:05Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-hppa-static as binfmt interpreter for hppa
2024-07-03T19:45:05Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-riscv32-static as binfmt interpreter for riscv32
2024-07-03T19:45:05Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-riscv64-static as binfmt interpreter for riscv64
2024-07-03T19:45:05Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-xtensa-static as binfmt interpreter for xtensa
2024-07-03T19:45:05Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-xtensaeb-static as binfmt interpreter for xtensaeb
2024-07-03T19:45:05Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-microblaze-static as binfmt interpreter for microblaze
2024-07-03T19:45:05Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-microblazeel-static as binfmt interpreter for microblazeel
2024-07-03T19:45:05Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-or1k-static as binfmt interpreter for or1k
2024-07-03T19:45:05Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-hexagon-static as binfmt interpreter for hexagon
2024-07-03T19:45:06Z #1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
2024-07-03T19:45:06Z #1 transferring dockerfile: 1.01kB done
2024-07-03T19:45:06Z #1 DONE 0.1s
2024-07-03T19:45:06Z 
2024-07-03T19:45:06Z #2 [auth] library/centos:pull token for registry-1.docker.io
2024-07-03T19:45:06Z #2 DONE 0.0s
2024-07-03T19:45:06Z 
2024-07-03T19:45:06Z #3 [auth] adoptopenjdk/openjdk14:pull token for registry-1.docker.io
2024-07-03T19:45:06Z #3 DONE 0.0s
2024-07-03T19:45:06Z 
2024-07-03T19:45:06Z #4 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/centos:7
2024-07-03T19:45:07Z #4 DONE 0.7s
2024-07-03T19:45:07Z 
2024-07-03T19:45:07Z #5 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/adoptopenjdk/openjdk14:armv7l-centos-jdk-14.0.2_12
2024-07-03T19:45:07Z #5 DONE 0.7s
2024-07-03T19:45:07Z 
2024-07-03T19:45:07Z #6 [internal] load .dockerignore
2024-07-03T19:45:07Z #6 transferring context: 2B done
2024-07-03T19:45:07Z #6 DONE 0.0s
2024-07-03T19:45:07Z 
2024-07-03T19:45:07Z #7 [stage-1 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/centos:7@sha256:be65f488b7764ad3638f236b7b515b3678369a5124c47b8d32916d6487418ea4
2024-07-03T19:45:07Z #7 resolve docker.io/library/centos:7@sha256:be65f488b7764ad3638f236b7b515b3678369a5124c47b8d32916d6487418ea4 0.0s done
2024-07-03T19:45:07Z #7 DONE 0.1s
2024-07-03T19:45:07Z 
2024-07-03T19:45:07Z #8 [build 1/4] FROM docker.io/adoptopenjdk/openjdk14:armv7l-centos-jdk-14.0.2_12@sha256:b4688d55ba6fe65b1810a6e5fbc2bed5e29ce977e696b6d2e9dbe092a44f0371
2024-07-03T19:45:07Z #8 resolve docker.io/adoptopenjdk/openjdk14:armv7l-centos-jdk-14.0.2_12@sha256:b4688d55ba6fe65b1810a6e5fbc2bed5e29ce977e696b6d2e9dbe092a44f0371 0.0s done
2024-07-03T19:45:07Z #8 sha256:0b55b0b0b22c736247c0d6dc7b21b2447811e560821da1daacedd4f669556a2e 0B / 198.00MB 0.2s

....................
Why is this, it seems to be saying the image songkong/songkong-arm32 does not exist but it seems to have built ok?
Note it says
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z WARNING: No output specified with docker-container driver. Build result will only remain in the build cache. To push result image into registry use --push or to load image into docker use --load
Could that be the issue ?
2024-07-12T08:03:56Z Cloning into '.'...
2024-07-12T08:03:57Z Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address '104.192.142.24' to the list of known hosts.
2024-07-12T08:03:58Z Reset branch 'master'
2024-07-12T08:03:58Z Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
2024-07-12T08:03:59Z Executing build hook...
2024-07-12T08:04:05Z mybuilder
2024-07-12T08:04:05Z #1 [internal] booting buildkit
2024-07-12T08:04:06Z #1 pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1
2024-07-12T08:04:14Z #1 pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1 8.2s done
2024-07-12T08:04:14Z #1 creating container buildx_buildkit_mybuilder0
2024-07-12T08:04:18Z #1 creating container buildx_buildkit_mybuilder0 3.9s done
2024-07-12T08:04:18Z #1 DONE 12.1s
2024-07-12T08:04:18Z Name:          mybuilder
2024-07-12T08:04:18Z Driver:        docker-container
2024-07-12T08:04:18Z Last Activity: 2024-07-12 08:04:05 +0000 UTC
2024-07-12T08:04:18Z 
2024-07-12T08:04:18Z Nodes:
2024-07-12T08:04:18Z Name:      mybuilder0
2024-07-12T08:04:18Z Endpoint:  unix:///var/run/docker.sock
2024-07-12T08:04:18Z Status:    running
2024-07-12T08:04:18Z Buildkit:  v0.14.1
2024-07-12T08:04:18Z Platforms: linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2, linux/amd64/v3, linux/386
2024-07-12T08:04:18Z Unable to find image 'multiarch/qemu-user-static:latest' locally
2024-07-12T08:04:18Z latest: Pulling from multiarch/qemu-user-static
2024-07-12T08:04:18Z 205dae5015e7: Pulling fs layer
2024-07-12T08:04:18Z 816739e52091: Pulling fs layer
2024-07-12T08:04:18Z 30abb83a18eb: Pulling fs layer
2024-07-12T08:04:18Z 0657daef200b: Pulling fs layer
2024-07-12T08:04:18Z 30c9c93f40b9: Pulling fs layer
2024-07-12T08:04:18Z 0657daef200b: Waiting
2024-07-12T08:04:18Z 30c9c93f40b9: Waiting
2024-07-12T08:04:18Z 816739e52091: Verifying Checksum
2024-07-12T08:04:18Z 816739e52091: Download complete
2024-07-12T08:04:18Z 30abb83a18eb: Verifying Checksum
2024-07-12T08:04:18Z 30abb83a18eb: Download complete
2024-07-12T08:04:18Z 205dae5015e7: Verifying Checksum
2024-07-12T08:04:18Z 205dae5015e7: Download complete
2024-07-12T08:04:18Z 0657daef200b: Verifying Checksum
2024-07-12T08:04:18Z 0657daef200b: Download complete
2024-07-12T08:04:19Z 205dae5015e7: Pull complete
2024-07-12T08:04:19Z 816739e52091: Pull complete
2024-07-12T08:04:19Z 30abb83a18eb: Pull complete
2024-07-12T08:04:20Z 0657daef200b: Pull complete
2024-07-12T08:04:20Z 30c9c93f40b9: Verifying Checksum
2024-07-12T08:04:20Z 30c9c93f40b9: Download complete
2024-07-12T08:04:26Z 30c9c93f40b9: Pull complete
2024-07-12T08:04:26Z Digest: sha256:fe60359c92e86a43cc87b3d906006245f77bfc0565676b80004cc666e4feb9f0
2024-07-12T08:04:26Z Status: Downloaded newer image for multiarch/qemu-user-static:latest
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-alpha-static as binfmt interpreter for alpha
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static as binfmt interpreter for arm
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-armeb-static as binfmt interpreter for armeb
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-sparc-static as binfmt interpreter for sparc
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-sparc32plus-static as binfmt interpreter for sparc32plus
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-sparc64-static as binfmt interpreter for sparc64
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-ppc-static as binfmt interpreter for ppc
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-ppc64-static as binfmt interpreter for ppc64
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-ppc64le-static as binfmt interpreter for ppc64le
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-m68k-static as binfmt interpreter for m68k
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-mips-static as binfmt interpreter for mips
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-mipsel-static as binfmt interpreter for mipsel
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-mipsn32-static as binfmt interpreter for mipsn32
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-mipsn32el-static as binfmt interpreter for mipsn32el
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-mips64-static as binfmt interpreter for mips64
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-mips64el-static as binfmt interpreter for mips64el
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-sh4-static as binfmt interpreter for sh4
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-sh4eb-static as binfmt interpreter for sh4eb
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-s390x-static as binfmt interpreter for s390x
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-aarch64-static as binfmt interpreter for aarch64
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-aarch64_be-static as binfmt interpreter for aarch64_be
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-hppa-static as binfmt interpreter for hppa
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-riscv32-static as binfmt interpreter for riscv32
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-riscv64-static as binfmt interpreter for riscv64
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-xtensa-static as binfmt interpreter for xtensa
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-xtensaeb-static as binfmt interpreter for xtensaeb
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-microblaze-static as binfmt interpreter for microblaze
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-microblazeel-static as binfmt interpreter for microblazeel
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-or1k-static as binfmt interpreter for or1k
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z Setting /usr/bin/qemu-hexagon-static as binfmt interpreter for hexagon
2024-07-12T08:04:31Z WARNING: No output specified with docker-container driver. Build result will only remain in the build cache. To push result image into registry use --push or to load image into docker use --load
2024-07-12T08:04:32Z #1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
2024-07-12T08:04:32Z #1 transferring dockerfile: 1.01kB done
2024-07-12T08:04:32Z #1 DONE 0.1s
2024-07-12T08:04:32Z 
2024-07-12T08:04:32Z #2 [auth] adoptopenjdk/openjdk14:pull token for registry-1.docker.io
2024-07-12T08:04:32Z #2 DONE 0.0s
2024-07-12T08:04:32Z 
2024-07-12T08:04:32Z #3 [auth] library/centos:pull token for registry-1.docker.io
2024-07-12T08:04:32Z #3 DONE 0.0s
2024-07-12T08:04:32Z 
2024-07-12T08:04:32Z #4 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/adoptopenjdk/openjdk14:armv7l-centos-jdk-14.0.2_12
2024-07-12T08:04:32Z #4 ...
2024-07-12T08:04:32Z 
2024-07-12T08:04:32Z #5 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/centos:7
2024-07-12T08:04:32Z #5 DONE 0.8s
2024-07-12T08:04:33Z 
2024-07-12T08:04:33Z #4 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/adoptopenjdk/openjdk14:armv7l-centos-jdk-14.0.2_12
2024-07-12T08:04:33Z #4 DONE 0.9s
2024-07-12T08:04:33Z 
2024-07-12T08:04:33Z #6 [internal] load .dockerignore
2024-07-12T08:04:33Z #6 transferring context: 2B 0.0s done
2024-07-12T08:04:33Z #6 DONE 0.0s
2024-07-12T08:04:33Z 
2024-07-12T08:04:33Z #7 [build 1/4] FROM docker.io/adoptopenjdk/openjdk14:armv7l-centos-jdk-14.0.2_12@sha256:b4688d55ba6fe65b1810a6e5fbc2bed5e29ce977e696b6d2e9dbe092a44f0371
2024-07-12T08:04:33Z #7 resolve docker.io/adoptopenjdk/openjdk14:armv7l-centos-jdk-14.0.2_12@sha256:b4688d55ba6fe65b1810a6e5fbc2bed5e29ce977e696b6d2e9dbe092a44f0371 0.0s done
2024-07-12T08:04:33Z #7 DONE 0.0s
2024-07-12T08:04:33Z 
2024-07-12T08:04:33Z #8 [stage-1 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/centos:7@sha256:be65f488b7764ad3638f236b7b515b3678369a5124c47b8d32916d6487418ea4
2024-07-12T08:04:33Z #8 resolve docker.io/library/centos:7@sha256:be65f488b7764ad3638f236b7b515b3678369a5124c47b8d32916d6487418ea4 0.0s done
2024-07-12T08:04:33Z #8 DONE 0.0s
2024-07-12T08:04:33Z 
2024-07-12T08:04:33Z #7 [build 1/4] FROM docker.io/adoptopenjdk/openjdk14:armv7l-centos-jdk-14.0.2_12@sha256:b4688d55ba6fe65b1810a6e5fbc2bed5e29ce977e696b6d2e9dbe092a44f0371
2024-07-12T08:04:33Z #7 DONE 0.1s
2024-07-12T08:04:33Z 
2024-07-12T08:04:33Z #8 [stage-1 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/centos:7@sha256:be65f488b7764ad3638f236b7b515b3678369a5124c47b8d32916d6487418ea4
2024-07-12T08:04:33Z #8 sha256:193bcbf05ff9ae85ac1a58cacd9c07f8f4297dc648808c347cceb3797ae603af 0B / 70.03MB 0.2s
2024-07-12T08:04:33Z #8 sha256:193bcbf05ff9ae85ac1a58cacd9c07f8f4297dc648808c347cceb3797ae603af 11.53MB / 70.03MB 0.5s
2024-07-12T08:04:33Z #8 sha256:193bcbf05ff9ae85ac1a58cacd9c07f8f4297dc648808c347cceb3797ae603af 32.51MB / 70.03MB 0.8s
2024-07-12T08:04:34Z #8 sha256:193bcbf05ff9ae85ac1a58cacd9c07f8f4297dc648808c347cceb3797ae603af 46.14MB / 70.03MB 1.1s
2024-07-12T08:04:34Z #8 sha256:193bcbf05ff9ae85ac1a58cacd9c07f8f4297dc648808c347cceb3797ae603af 58.72MB / 70.03MB 1.2s
2024-07-12T08:04:34Z #8 sha256:193bcbf05ff9ae85ac1a58cacd9c07f8f4297dc648808c347cceb3797ae603af 70.03MB / 70.03MB 1.5s
2024-07-12T08:04:35Z #8 sha256:193bcbf05ff9ae85ac1a58cacd9c07f8f4297dc648808c347cceb3797ae603af 70.03MB / 70.03MB 2.5s done
2024-07-12T08:04:35Z #8 DONE 2.8s
2024-07-12T08:04:35Z 
2024-07-12T08:04:35Z #7 [build 1/4] FROM docker.io/adoptopenjdk/openjdk14:armv7l-centos-jdk-14.0.2_12@sha256:b4688d55ba6fe65b1810a6e5fbc2bed5e29ce977e696b6d2e9dbe092a44f0371
2024-07-12T08:04:35Z #7 sha256:0b55b0b0b22c736247c0d6dc7b21b2447811e560821da1daacedd4f669556a2e 132.12MB / 198.00MB 2.7s
2024-07-12T08:04:35Z #7 sha256:83c03e4400804660ec377662b61bf20e68e92abd1a635726b631c1803e63f56a 66.36MB / 66.36MB 2.7s
2024-07-12T08:04:36Z #7 sha256:0b55b0b0b22c736247c0d6dc7b21b2447811e560821da1daacedd4f669556a2e 149.95MB / 198.00MB 3.0s
2024-07-12T08:04:36Z #7 sha256:0b55b0b0b22c736247c0d6dc7b21b2447811e560821da1daacedd4f669556a2e 161.48MB / 198.00MB 3.5s
2024-07-12T08:04:36Z #7 sha256:83c03e4400804660ec377662b61bf20e68e92abd1a635726b631c1803e63f56a 66.36MB / 66.36MB 3.4s done
2024-07-12T08:04:37Z #7 sha256:0b55b0b0b22c736247c0d6dc7b21b2447811e560821da1daacedd4f669556a2e 182.45MB / 198.00MB 3.9s
2024-07-12T08:04:37Z #7 sha256:0b55b0b0b22c736247c0d6dc7b21b2447811e560821da1daacedd4f669556a2e 197.13MB / 198.00MB 4.1s
2024-07-12T08:04:39Z #7 sha256:0b55b0b0b22c736247c0d6dc7b21b2447811e560821da1daacedd4f669556a2e 198.00MB / 198.00MB 6.7s done
2024-07-12T08:04:39Z #7 DONE 6.8s
2024-07-12T08:04:39Z 
2024-07-12T08:04:39Z #8 [stage-1 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/centos:7@sha256:be65f488b7764ad3638f236b7b515b3678369a5124c47b8d32916d6487418ea4
2024-07-12T08:04:39Z #8 extracting sha256:193bcbf05ff9ae85ac1a58cacd9c07f8f4297dc648808c347cceb3797ae603af
2024-07-12T08:04:41Z #8 extracting sha256:193bcbf05ff9ae85ac1a58cacd9c07f8f4297dc648808c347cceb3797ae603af 4.7s done
2024-07-12T08:04:41Z #8 DONE 7.6s
2024-07-12T08:04:41Z 
2024-07-12T08:04:41Z #7 [build 1/4] FROM docker.io/adoptopenjdk/openjdk14:armv7l-centos-jdk-14.0.2_12@sha256:b4688d55ba6fe65b1810a6e5fbc2bed5e29ce977e696b6d2e9dbe092a44f0371
2024-07-12T08:04:41Z #7 extracting sha256:83c03e4400804660ec377662b61bf20e68e92abd1a635726b631c1803e63f56a
2024-07-12T08:04:46Z #7 extracting sha256:83c03e4400804660ec377662b61bf20e68e92abd1a635726b631c1803e63f56a 5.1s done
2024-07-12T08:04:46Z #7 extracting sha256:0b55b0b0b22c736247c0d6dc7b21b2447811e560821da1daacedd4f669556a2e
2024-07-12T08:04:49Z #7 ...
2024-07-12T08:04:49Z 
2024-07-12T08:04:49Z #9 [stage-1 2/4] RUN mkdir -p /opt
2024-07-12T08:04:49Z #9 DONE 7.8s
2024-07-12T08:04:49Z 
2024-07-12T08:04:49Z #7 [build 1/4] FROM docker.io/adoptopenjdk/openjdk14:armv7l-centos-jdk-14.0.2_12@sha256:b4688d55ba6fe65b1810a6e5fbc2bed5e29ce977e696b6d2e9dbe092a44f0371
2024-07-12T08:04:51Z #7 extracting sha256:0b55b0b0b22c736247c0d6dc7b21b2447811e560821da1daacedd4f669556a2e 5.0s done
2024-07-12T08:04:51Z #7 DONE 17.0s
2024-07-12T08:04:51Z 
2024-07-12T08:04:51Z #10 [build 2/4] RUN /opt/java/openjdk/bin/jlink --module-path=/opt/java/openjdk/jmods --add-modules java.desktop,java.datatransfer,java.logging,java.management,java.naming,java.net.http,java.prefs,java.scripting,java.sql,jdk.management,jdk.unsupported,jdk.jcmd,jdk.crypto.ec,jdk.dynalink --output /opt/songkong/jre
2024-07-12T08:04:51Z #10 0.204 /bin/sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
2024-07-12T08:06:21Z #10 DONE 89.6s
2024-07-12T08:06:21Z 
2024-07-12T08:06:21Z #11 [build 3/4] RUN mkdir -p /opt  && curl http://www.jthink.net/songkong/downloads/current/songkong-linux-docker.tgz?val=1169.1| tar -C /opt -xzf - && find /opt/songkong -perm /u+x -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod a+x
2024-07-12T08:06:21Z #11 0.231 /bin/sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
2024-07-12T08:06:21Z #11 0.578   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
2024-07-12T08:06:21Z #11 0.618                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
2024-07-12T08:06:41Z #11 0.626 
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  1 86.9M    1 1097k    0     0  1396k      0  0:01:03 --:--:--  0:01:03 1434k
  6 86.9M    6 5801k    0     0  3252k      0  0:00:27  0:00:01  0:00:26 3290k
 11 86.9M   11 10.2M    0     0  3758k      0  0:00:23  0:00:02  0:00:21 3786k
 17 86.9M   17 15.1M    0     0  4095k      0  0:00:21  0:00:03  0:00:18 4117k
 22 86.9M   22 19.8M    0     0  4243k      0  0:00:20  0:00:04  0:00:16 4262k
 27 86.9M   27 24.1M    0     0  4269k      0  0:00:20  0:00:05  0:00:15 4720k
 33 86.9M   33 28.8M    0     0  4351k      0  0:00:20  0:00:06  0:00:14 4742k
 37 86.9M   37 32.7M    0     0  4316k      0  0:00:20  0:00:07  0:00:13 4626k
 42 86.9M   42 37.0M    0     0  4319k      0  0:00:20  0:00:08  0:00:12 4489k
 47 86.9M   47 41.4M    0     0  4345k      0  0:00:20  0:00:09  0:00:11 4441k
 52 86.9M   52 45.6M    0     0  4330k      0  0:00:20  0:00:10  0:00:10 4400k
 58 86.9M   58 50.6M    0     0  4400k      0  0:00:20  0:00:11  0:00:09 4466k
 63 86.9M   63 54.8M    0     0  4394k      0  0:00:20  0:00:12  0:00:08 4515k
 66 86.9M   66 57.8M    0     0  4299k      0  0:00:20  0:00:13  0:00:07 4263k
 71 86.9M   71 62.3M    0     0  4321k      0  0:00:20  0:00:14  0:00:06 4275k
 76 86.9M   76 66.7M    0     0  4328k      0  0:00:20  0:00:15  0:00:05 4324k
 83 86.9M   83 72.2M    0     0  4410k      0  0:00:20  0:00:16  0:00:04 4433k
 89 86.9M   89 78.2M    0     0  4508k      0  0:00:19  0:00:17  0:00:02 4800k
 93 86.9M   93 81.7M    0     0  4454k      0  0:00:19  0:00:18  0:00:01 4881k
 99 86.9M   99 86.8M    0     0  4496k      0  0:00:19  0:00:19 --:--:-- 5013k
100 86.9M  100 86.9M    0     0  4489k      0  0:00:19  0:00:19 --:--:-- 5113k
2024-07-12T08:06:42Z #11 DONE 21.2s
2024-07-12T08:06:42Z 
2024-07-12T08:06:42Z #12 [build 4/4] RUN rm -fr /opt/java
2024-07-12T08:06:42Z #12 0.262 /bin/sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
2024-07-12T08:06:42Z #12 DONE 0.5s
2024-07-12T08:06:43Z 
2024-07-12T08:06:43Z #13 [stage-1 3/4] COPY --from=build /opt/songkong /opt/songkong
2024-07-12T08:06:45Z #13 DONE 2.2s
2024-07-12T08:06:45Z 
2024-07-12T08:06:45Z #14 [stage-1 4/4] WORKDIR /opt/songkong
2024-07-12T08:06:45Z #14 DONE 0.1s
2024-07-12T08:06:45Z Image not found! Build may have failed.
2024-07-12T08:06:45Z build hook failed! (1)


At last check, Docker Hub builds do not support multi-platform options. You can follow the progress on that at:

https://github.com/docker/roadmap/issues/109
https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/1261
https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/1874

The most popular method to build multi-platform images these days is to use GitHub Actions. With bitbucket, it looks like they support multi-platform builds in pipelines.

From the updated question, there are a few things that don't align with the documented capabilities of the hooks in Docker Hub builders:

You don't push the image in there, you only build it, which means they are expecting the image to be output to the local docker engine.
You shouldn't specify the image name, that's up to Docker to provide with variables.
For buildx, you want to configure qemu before the builder.
There's no need for persistence or resetting qemu.

The resulting hooks/build file would look like:
#!/bin/bash

set -e

docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static:register
docker buildx create --name mybuilder --use
# the variables in the below command are populated by Hub and should not be altered
# the --load is important here to output to the docker engine
docker buildx build --platform linux/arm/v7 -f "${DOCKERFILE_PATH}" -t "${IMAGE_NAME}" --load .

Note that this gets into undocumented behaviors of the Hub builders since they don't specify support for buildx.
Hooks are documented here: https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/advanced/. And details of other people using hooks can be found in links from the above GitHub issues.

I dont want to build a multi-platform image I just want to be able to build my DockerFile designed for arm on DockerHub, is that possible?

The issues tend to go together for a lot of users. If they implement the second link, they'll likely support multi platform builds too.

@PaulTaylor have you had a chance to try the above suggestion?

Yes, thankyou it worked, (dont know why your solution is not documented as seems a pretty standard requirement being able to build for arm), Ive adwarded you the bounty

Context
Yes it is possible to build an x86 and Arm 32-bit version of your application in DockerHub with multi-arch build support. Your build is failing because you are building an arm/v7 image on x86 hardware, causing an architecture mismatch creating an exec format error. There are two general options available to build multi-architecture images:
Option 1: Separate Builds on Target Architectures

Build the x86 and Arm 32-bit images separately on the architecture they target, and combine the images into one 'multi-arch image' via the docker manifest command. Note this requires your build process to have access to x86 and Arm 32-bit machines. You can use separate Dockerfiles for each architecture (as you have today), or combine your app into a single Dockerfile with multi-stage builds supporting both architectures.

Option 2: Cross-Platform Builds Using Docker Buildx

Build the x86 and Arm 32-bit images on the same machine (x86-based), and use docker buildx to create an Arm 32-bit image via the emulation tool QEMU. In this option you can also use separate Dockerfiles for each architecture and combine the images with docker manifest, or a single Dockerfile with a command like docker buildx build --push --platform linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64/v8,linux/amd64 \ --tag your-username/multiarch-example:buildx-latest .

To change your current setup the least, you should take Option 2 using your separate Dockerfiles. You'll need to then modify your DockerHub build step in three ways - install QEMU, use docker buildx for your Arm 32-bit Dockerfile, and combining your x86 and Arm 32-bit Docker images with docker manifest.
For context, the buildx command was released at DockerCon 2019 via a collaboration between Docker and Arm; being part of the team that created it, I can attest to its usefulness for your use-case and multi-arch builds in general.
First, however, you need to fix your Dockerfile targeting the Arm architecture as the 'centos:7' base image only works on x86. You should replace it with 'arm32v7/centos:7' instead.

DockerHub build edits
To break it down, your process will look like the following:

Have two separate Dockerfiles, one for each architecture.
Build & push the amd64 image as you are today on DockerHub, which by default uses docker build.
Build & push the arm/v7 image using docker buildx using DockerHub's custom build hooks.
In a custom push phase for your arm/v7 image, create and push a multi-arch manifest with docker manifest.

By your Arm 32-bit DockerFile, create a folder called hooks and add two files: build and post_push.
The build file will look like this (with debug steps to help fix any issues):
#!/bin/bash

# set debug flag to help uncover issues
set -e

# Set up buildx. Inspecting ensures buildx is configured correctly and ready, and the final command runs a container to set up QEMU, enabling the Arm emulation for cross-platform building.
docker buildx create --name mybuilder --use
docker buildx inspect --bootstrap
docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset -p yes

# Verify qemu is set up correctly
docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --show-registrations

# Build the image
docker buildx build --platform linux/arm/v7 -t songkong/songkong-arm32:latest -f Dockerfile .

# Verify the image exists, quit script if not
docker images | grep songkong/songkong-arm32 || { echo "Image not found! Build may have failed."; exit 1; }

# Push the image
docker push songkong/songkong-arm32:latest

The post_push file:
#!/bin/bash

# Create & push the multi-arch manifest combining x86 and arm/v7 images
docker pull username/repository:tag-amd64

docker manifest create username/repository:tag \
  --amend username/repository:tag-amd64 \
  --amend username/repository:tag-arm32

docker manifest push username/repository:tag

When DockerHub executes the automatic build for your Arm 32-bit DockerFile, the build commands will be overwritten with your new buildx commands, and after pushing will pull your already build x86 image and combine it with the Arm 32-bit image.
Running
When you want to run this image on x86 and Arm 32-bit hardware, Docker will automatically detect where it is running and pull the correct architecture version. Your standard docker pull username/repository:tag will work fine.

For those using GitHub Actions, you can refer to this .yml file to see how to use docker buildx in your CI pipelines to build multi-arch images.

Thanks but Im not qwuite following it, you say I need to fix by arm32 build to use arm32 version, but it is first line is a arm32 version 'FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk14:armv7l-centos-jdk-14.0.2_12 AS build' and it was working on my arm based hardware until the hardware broke. What Im not really clear about is if I modify the arm DockerFile can it then be built automatically by DockerHub when I modify it or can I only build it locally with docker on my computer. Is buildx something that can be used on DockerHub or just something I can use to build locally on my computer?

If your Arm-specific Dockerfile works on Arm hardware, then you can use the same file to build it automatically on DockerHub using buildx. You need to change your DockerHub build script to call docker buildx as described in my answer above, which will emulate 32-bit Arm hardware to build Arm-compatible Dockerfile even while running on the x86 hardware. This way you can build the Arm Docker image without needing Arm-based hardware.

OKay so I cant see where to create a Dockerhub build script, I just have the DockerFile and that triggers a build, where doyou create a build script?

ive created another bounty for you because Iforgot to award theotherone in time

I updated my answer to make clearer how to modify your DockerHub automated build by using DockerHub hooks. It should answer your question.

If you (and others) are using GitHub Actions with Docker Build Cloud, this tutorial overviews how to create multi-arch containers all using GitHub Actions, without emulation or self-hosted runners:

HI, have updated my question with attempt at your solution,it nearly worked but failed on pushing tag, do yo know why please?

Sorry my edit got lost, i have now redone it so you can see what I tried and how it failed.

Ive created another bounty for you and would appreiate itif you could take another look for me and see why your solution is not quite working please.

Yes have taken a look. I'm not quite sure exactly why the push failed without seeing more of the logs. Debug steps: Verify QEMU sets up correctly: docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --version. Then split up your main Dockerfile build & push steps, and look at the logs to see specifically the issue is. Build first: docker buildx build --platform linux/arm/v7 -t songkong/songkong-arm32:latest -f Dockerfile . Then docker images to confirm it is local, and push with docker buildx build --platform linux/arm/v7 -t songkong/songkong-arm32:latest -f Dockerfile --push .

HI I have added the full log to question now, cant see any errors until end hope that is enough for you becase I can't see a way to break down build on dockerhub but the DockerFile did build fine on my arm32 machine until it broke.

Try the modified build script in the answer, it is formatted to provide robust debug information and explicitly check if the image was built correctly. This will provide a clear indication of where the issue is to resolve

Debug version failed early on with write issue, updated question with logs

I took out the qemu reistry line and retried buid, it seemed to build okay except couldnt find image. I noticed line earlier on that says '2024-07-12T08:04:31Z WARNING: No output specified with docker-container driver. Build result will only remain in the build cache. To push result image into registry use --push or to load image into docker use --load'. (updated question with latest log)  could that be the issue ?

It doesn't seem the QEMU is causing the error. The warning means you either need to add a '--load' or '--push' command during the docker buildx build step of your Dockerfile. The --load will load the image locally which can then be pushed in the next step. That is probably best during your debugging situation now. Otherwise you can add the '--push' command directly to your build step to build/push at the same time.

Yes that was the issue, your solution was missing the --load option.
